# Retrieving result from multiple many to many relation tables with limit

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

Table relations image is in this link http://www.serofero.net/mvb-table-relation.png

I am using php as server side programming language and MySQL as database.

**Problem Description**

User adds a new venue. One venue may have multiple beverages, events, features so on and so forth. Now , I want such a query or magic so that I could collect all the beverages, events, features, foods, styles, types, event_options and space_requirements related to each venue along with its venue_id, name, description, capacity, min_rate, max_rate, location (from locations table). Also I need to offset and limit the result so that I could implement pagination in backend. But the challange is that the limit should limit the number of venues not its beverages, foods, styles etc.

I am also wondering to collect the result in php array as below:

```
    $result = array(
    0=> array(
    "name" => "Venue A",
    "description" => "Venue A description",
    "capacity" => "Venue A capacity",
    "location" => "Venue A location",
    "beverages" => array('beverage1','beverage23','beverage7',...),
    "events" => array('event8','event17','event19','event4',...),
    "features" => array('features1',...),
    "foods" => array(),
    "styles" => array(),
    "types" => array('type7', 'type14', 'type23',...),
    "event_options" => array(),
    "space_requirements" => array()
    )
    ,
    1=> array(
    "name" => "Venue B",
    "description" => "Venue B description",
    "capacity" => "Venue B capacity",
    "location" => "Venue B location",
    "beverages" => array('beverage1'),
    "events" => array('event2','event7','event9','event4',...),
    "features" => array(),
    "foods" => array(),
    "styles" => array('style1', 'style2',...),
    "types" => array('type47', 'type4', 'type3',...),
    "event_options" => array(),
    "space_requirements" => array()
    )
    );
```

Today is 5th day I am trying to figure out the solution but I have been failed all the time. Below is the snippet of MySQL Query that I could write till now.

```
    SELECT v.name, e.event, t.type, s.style
    FROM venues v

    LEFT JOIN venue_events ve ON v.venue_id = ve.venue_id
    LEFT JOIN events e ON e.event_id = ve.event_id

    LEFT JOIN venue_types vt ON v.venue_id = vt.venue_id
    LEFT JOIN types t ON t.type_id = vt.type_id

    LEFT JOIN venue_styles vs ON v.venue_id = vs.venue_id
    LEFT JOIN styles s ON s.style_id = vs.style_id

    WHERE v.venue_id IN (SELECT venue_id FROM venues) LIMIT 0,5 
    /* I want to limit the number of "venues" but the LIMIT 0,5 limits the number of   'events', 'types' , 'styles' the "venue" have. And this is the main problem.

    I have also tried :
    WHERE v.venue_id IN (SELECT venue_id FROM venues LIMIT 0,5) but it raises the MySQL error. 
    */
```

But I dont know what to do next to get the result as I mentioned above.

Please help me.

Thankyou.

Comment: You can't use `LIMIT` in subquery.

Comment: Oh yes, but I need limited results, any idea please.

Comment: First run the inner query and embed its result in main query.

Comment: Ok I got it, thankyou very much Yogesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ven.venue_id, ven.name, e.event_id, e.event, t.type_id, t.type, s.style_id, s.style

FROM (SELECT * FROM venues v LIMIT 0,5) ven /*This line does magic for me*/

LEFT JOIN venue_events ve ON ven.venue_id = ve.venue_id
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.event_id = ve.event_id

LEFT JOIN venue_types vt ON ven.venue_id = vt.venue_id
LEFT JOIN types t ON t.type_id = vt.type_id

LEFT JOIN venue_styles vs ON ven.venue_id = vs.venue_id
LEFT JOIN styles s ON s.style_id = vs.style_id
```